# Convert ntext to varbinary(max)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to convert column values from `ntext` to `varbinary(max)` in `SQL server 2000 R2`?

Doing a workaround I found, initially I need to convert from `ntext` to `nvarchar()` then from `nvarchar()` to `varbinary(max)`.

Comment: `ntext` is deprecated and you shouldn't be using it anyway.

Comment: Yes, As mentioned above, I want the column to be in varbinary(max). How can i convert?

Comment: Why do you want it in `varbinary(max)`? The replacement for `ntext`, for storing long unicode strings, is `nvarchar(max)`

Comment: Because i want the data to be stored in binary format.

Comment: It is stored in binary format anyway. Casting `nvarchar` to `varbinary` doesn't affect how it is stored it just makes it more difficult to work with.

Comment: I don't understand . "It is stored in binary format anyway"

Answer (score 0):

No this is not a supported direct conversion.

As shown in the [Data Type Conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx) topic ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRKXL.png)) you can only cast from ntext to one of the other string datatypes or to XML.

But you don't need to do this anyway.

The argument

> Because i want the data to be stored in binary format.

doesn't make sense as it won't affect the physical storage anyway. 
See below that the actual bytes stored are the same.

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
A NVARCHAR(MAX),
B VARBINARY(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO T 
SELECT N'foobar',
       CAST(N'foobar' AS VARBINARY(MAX))
```

[image]

It just affects how the bytes are interpreted logically. Storing as varbinary datatype would make the data more difficult to work with (need to cast back to `nvarchar` to use as a string) and your application more fragile. [Conversions between any data type and the binary data types are not guaranteed to be the same between versions of SQL Server.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx)

Comment: Thanks martin. I appreciate your support and guidance.The image answered my query.

Comment: What a curious bit of Microsoftese: "Conversions between any data type and the binary data types are not guaranteed to be the same between versions of SQL Server." It could mean that the supported conversions might change, e.g. SS2014 supports implicit conversion from `binary` to `datetime` but the next release might not. Or it could mean that a supported conversion might do something different, e.g. a conversion that returned `42` in the prior version could return `666` in the current version. Or both. Or something else. At least it's documented.

Comment: @HABO What they are warning about is that they are free to change the internal binary representation of datatypes without warning and we shouldn't be relying on them remaining fixed.